# confident proportion

Tags: statistical-significance, proportion

I conduct an experiment and I get #installs=2 out of #clicks=100, I am interested in the proportion #installs/#clicks. Here, I get ratio to be 2%.

I conduct another experiment and get #installs=200 out of #clicks=10000. Again, the proportion is 2%.

I was wondering which scenario gives better representation of the ratio in the population. What are the mechanical/statistical ways to determine this?
(Apologies if I am not able to articulate the question accurately; I would appreciate if someone can help me in arriving at right questions in this scenario)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this via the Beta distribution. The probability density in the case of 2 out of 100 is $Beta(1+2, 1+98)$, whilst the one of 200 out of 10000 is $Beta(1+200, 1+9998)$. A plot of both shows, how much more precise the latter examination is:

[image: Two Beta distributions]

Or if we look at just the first tenth of that x axis:

[image]

On the x-axis we have all possible "true" ratios and on the y the densitiy of the probability of this ratio. Areas under the curve depict the probability of the true ration being within a certain intervall. Because you have more data in the second case, you can make a more precise definition of the "true value". This is a so called Baysian approach with a "flat prior" (make shure to understand that concept before using this thing".

A more Frequentist way to look at the picture would be a confidence interval of the true ratio. Whatever a condfidence interval acutally is, it can be computed like this in `R`. However, be shure to understand what a confidence intervall truely is and not what people tend to think, what it is, before using this thing.

```
> binom.test(2, 100)$conf.int
[1] 0.002431337 0.070383932
attr(,"conf.level")
[1] 0.95
> binom.test(200, 10000)$conf.int
[1] 0.01734654 0.02293792
attr(,"conf.level")
[1] 0.95
```

### Edit:

I made a mistake above. In the 200:9800 case, the Beta-Distribution is obviously $Beta(1+200, 1+9800)$ and not, as I wrote above, $Beta(1+200, 1+9998).$  I did not correct the plots above as it will not make much difference to the plots and nobody is going to read actual numbers from the plots above.

Comment: In later case, it can be seen from the plot that the estimate is more precise. How can I use this information to arrive at some thresholds for clicks and/or installs using which I can say that the proportion obtained using those clicks and installs is "significantly" precise.
Here, first I want to formulate the notion of "significantly" precise ratio and second I want to arrive at some thresholds for clicks and/or installs.

Comment: Basically, if p-hat is estimated proportion(in this case it is 2%), and I want it to be within 1% of p(actual proportion of the population; which I don't know) at 95% confidence level, then how big my numerator and/or denominator should be?

Comment: As I wrote above: "Areas under the curve depict the probability of the true ration being within a certain intervall." I `R` you can find the area under the curve from $-\infty$ to any given value through the function `pbeta`. In the 2:98 case and for the interval (1.9% - 2.1%) the probability is `pbeta(0.021,3,99) - pbeta(0.019,3,99)` roughly 5.5%. In the 200:9800 case it is `pbeta(0.021,201,9801) - pbeta(0.019,201,9801)` roughly 52.5% chance.

Comment: For a Frequentist approach ("significance") you can do a power analysis. If an answer in `R` is ok: Search for package `pwr` and the function `pwr::pwr.p.test`.